# check if current time in India is between a particular time range in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I used to include some dependent classes to change the timezone. But how can you do it in PHP without adding any dependencies? How to check if current time in India [for example] is between a particular time range and display appropriate message

*EDIT bcoz of downvotes:* I myself provided answer to this, that's the reason I posted this question, to help someone in future. That's the reason why the question appears to be without any efforts/no-code as I have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
//echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');  // prints 2015-08-25


$currentTime = time();

// if you want to check the hour only. This can also be checked via mktime(16, 0, 0)
if (((int) date('H', $currentTime)) >= 16) {
    echo "current time is greater than 4pm";
} else {
    echo "current time is less than 4 pm";
}

// if you want to check the hour and minute together
if($currentTime > mktime(16, 29, 0)) {
    echo " We're sorry, This service is available only before 4pm";
} else {
    echo "";
}

// if you want to check the hour and minute together in a range
if($currentTime < mktime(6, 0, 0) || $currentTime > mktime(16, 30, 0)) {
    echo " We're sorry, This service is available only between 6 AM and 4:30 PM";
} else {
    echo "";
}

// check if current date/time is greater than a particular date/time
if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("2015-08-26 16:00:00")) {
    # current time is greater than 2015-08-25 16:00:00
    echo "This coupon is expired.";
}

?>
```